# Both FindMinimum and NMinimize have trouble

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a function I wrote, in a not entirely elegant (but functional) way. As a side note, if you have advice on how to write this in a smarter way, that's also welcome.

In any case, the function is as follows:

```
LL = 1.74; CC = 300 10^-6; RR = 20000; CCJ = 30 10^-6; CCκ = 
 80 10^-6;
rules = {C1 -> CC - CCJ - CCκ, C2 -> CC - 2 CCJ, 
   C3 -> CC - CCJ, R1 -> RR, R2 -> RR, R3 -> RR, CJ1 -> CCJ, 
   CJ2 -> CCJ, CJ3 -> CCJ, Cκ -> CCκ, L1 -> LL, 
   L2 -> LL, L3 -> LL, ω -> 2 π ν, 
   Zc -> 50, ω0 -> 2 π 7.0};


GammaEq[ω_, rules_] := 
 Module[{ain = 1., K, 
   Cκt, κ1, γ1, γ2, γ3, MC, 
   iC, ω1, ω2, ω3, J12, J23, J13, Dm, 
   r, Γ, Av},
  K = 1 + (1/(Zc Cκ ω))^2; 
  Cκt = Cκ (1 - 1/K);

  MC = ( {
      {C1 + Cκt + CJ1 + CJ3, -CJ1, -CJ3},
      {-CJ1, C2 + CJ1 + CJ2, -CJ2},
      {-CJ3, -CJ2, C3 + CJ2 + CJ3}
     } ) // FullSimplify;
  iC = Inverse[MC];

  κ1 = 1/(K Zc ) iC[[1, 1]]; γ1 = 
   1/R1  iC[[1, 1]]; γ2 = 1/R2  iC[[2, 2]]; γ3 = 
   1/R3  iC[[3, 3]];
  ω1 = Sqrt[1/L1 iC[[1, 1]]]; ω2 = Sqrt[
   1/L2 iC[[2, 2]]]; ω3 = Sqrt[1/L3 iC[[3, 3]]];
  J12 = 1/2 iC[[1, 2]]/Sqrt[iC[[1, 1]] iC[[2, 2]]]
     Sqrt[ω1 ω2];
  J23 = 1/2 iC[[2, 3]]/Sqrt[iC[[2, 2]] iC[[3, 3]]]
     Sqrt[ω2 ω3];
  J13 = 1/2 iC[[1, 3]]/Sqrt[iC[[1, 1]] iC[[3, 3]]]
     Sqrt[ω1 ω3];
  Dm = {{ω1 - ω + (I γ1)/2 + (I κ1)/2, J12, J13},
        {J12, ω2 - ω + (I γ2)/2, J23},
        {J13, J23, ω3 - ω + (I γ3)/2}} /. rules // FullSimplify;
  Av = I Sqrt[{κ1, 0, 0}] ain /. rules;
  r = LinearSolve[Dm, Av];
  Γ = 1 - Sqrt[{κ1, 0, 0}].r/ain /. rules;
  Return[Γ]
  ]
```

What I then want is to plot the absolute value of the function

```
Plot[Abs[GammaEq[2*Pi*ω, rules]], {ω, 6, 8}]
```

which clearly has three minima:
[image]

However, I'm having trouble finding the minima. I can approximately see them from the figure, but it would be nice to have a more exact number. Both FindMinimum and NMinimize complain about the numbers not being real (even though they are when you evaluate the function, as seen in the plot) which I suppose is due to the way the function is written. Could anyone recommend an approach?

Comment: There's no need for an explicit `Return[]` at the end, if you remove the semicolon after the assignment on `Γ`.

Comment: …why did you delete the code associated with your question? Unless you can give a good reason, I'll roll it back.

Comment: Not on purpose actually, I think I pressed space at the end and took it all away. Thanks!

Comment: You had an unpleasant `MatrixForm` expression in your code. These very frequently cause problems: the documentation is not correct to say that "`MatrixForm` is a wrapper that affects display and not evaluation". I have removed it and substituted it with the standard form input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define `GammaEq` so that it takes only numeric arguments,

```
 Clear[GammaEQ]
 GammaEq[ω_?NumericQ, rules_] := ...
```

and give `FindMinimum` a good starting point:

```
FindMinimum[Abs[GammaEq[2*π*ω, rules]], {ω, 6}]
```

> ```
> {0.62902, {ω -> 6.39389}}
> ```

As for the code, since this is a purely numerical function, you can speed it up tremendously by applying your rules ASAP; e.g.:

```
 MC = ( {
       {C1 + Cκt + CJ1 + CJ3, -CJ1, -CJ3},
       {-CJ1, C2 + CJ1 + CJ2, -CJ2},
       {-CJ3, -CJ2, C3 + CJ2 + CJ3}
          } ) /. rules;
γ1 = 1/R1  iC[[1, 1]] /. rules;
```

etc. (no need for that `FullSimplify` now)

Just so you know, one of your rules : `ω -> 2 π ν` doesn't do anything, since `ω` already has a numeric value by the time you apply the rule.

Comment: Very interesting, and helpful. Would you perhaps know what's going on for this to be needed?

Comment: `NMinimize[{Abs[GammaEq[2*Pi*w, rules]], 6 < w < 8}, w, 
 Method -> "NelderMead"]` seems to give a better approximation

Comment: @george2079 Do you mean that for every expression that includes the numerical values, I should use the /. rules? I'm not entirely clear on what you meant by that, but the word tremendously definitely caught my attention.

Comment: The symbolic `MC / FullSimplify` was the big time waster.. but apply the rules to all the gamma's and omegas as well ( The plot renders in less than a second now, was over a minute ).   The `NumericQ` issue is common to most functions that perform an "apparently" purely numeric task (`NIntegrate`, `FindRoot`, etc ). They initially do a symbolic evaluation, so in case where that makes no sense you force them to skip it essentially.

Comment: I see, yeah, the simplify was initially there to see if what I did made sense, suppose the evaluator doesn't care about that indeed. Thanks a lot for the help!